# Perfect AC sinusoidal wave dimmer with PWM from micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, ac, pwm, dimmer, igbt

I am designing a circuit for controlling speed of a AC fan using Arduino UNO, this is how the circuit looks like [image: Circuit Diagram].

In this circuit the waveform generated for load is not perfectly sinusoidal,what i want is to generate a perfect sine wave with low voltage , that some thing looks like the below circuit:-

[image: AC PWM waveform]

Supply voltage available is 5v. Please help me with the approach or circuit that can be used to achieve this.

[REF of Images](http://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/)http://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/

Comment: You won't get what you want using a triac dimmer circuit but, it's really not clear what you actually want. I mean if you want a perfect sinewave (they don't exist BTW) then make an oscillator like a Colpitts or wein bridge type.

Comment: What I want is, when PWM signal is applied,the waveform showed in second fig must be appear on output load rather then waveform I showed in first fig.

Comment: With triac you can not achieve you goal.  Tryi to use MOSFET. Check application note 60 from Vishay.

Comment: I would like to amplify @Andy_aka's comment. You won't be able to control fan speed with a triac dimmer circuit. The speed of the fan motor depends upon the frequency of the AC.

Comment: For an AC signal a single MOSFET won't work; you'd need two (one to block each direction). You might look into GTO (thyristors or triacs) where a negative pulse on the gate can turn them off again. And even then, if you vary the AC voltage, there's no guarantee that'll vary the fan speed in a linear fashion.